# Processing stuck in step Write mutations to Cloud Spanner to Spanner without outputting or completing in state process

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

Processing stuck in step Sink-Spanner/Write mutations to Cloud Spanner/Write mutations to Spanner for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process

Write to Spanner is happening, but throwing this error

```java
PCollectionTuple spanMutTuple = pColIfEnrichMsgs.apply("CreateMutation",
                ParDo.of(new SpannerMutation(options, ttSpanMutOutMsgs, erroMessage))
                     .withOutputTags(ttSpanMutOutMsgs, TupleTagList.of(erroMessage))
);

/*...*/
pColSpanMut.apply("Sink-Spanner", 
    SpannerIO.write()
             .withInstanceId(options.getOutputSpannerInstanceId())
             .withDatabaseId(options.getOutputSpannerDatabaseId())
             .withMaxNumMutations(options.getOutputSpannerMaxMutations().get())
             .withBatchSizeBytes(options.getOutputSpannerBatchSizeBytes().get() * 1048576)
             .withFailureMode(FailureMode.REPORT_FAILURES)
             .withProjectId(options.getOutputSpannerProjectId().get())
);
```

Expected: No warning/errors like it is reporting in google cloud dataflow UI.

```
Processing stuck in step Sink-Spanner/Write mutations to Cloud Spanner/Write mutations to Spanner for at least 05m00s without outputting or completing in state process
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
  at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:469)
  at com.google.api.core.AbstractApiFuture.get(AbstractApiFuture.java:56)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.spi.v1.GapicSpannerRpc.get(GapicSpannerRpc.java:556)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.spi.v1.GapicSpannerRpc.commit(GapicSpannerRpc.java:528)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$SessionImpl$2.call(SpannerImpl.java:822)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$SessionImpl$2.call(SpannerImpl.java:819)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl.runWithRetries(SpannerImpl.java:251)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerImpl$SessionImpl.writeAtLeastOnce(SpannerImpl.java:818)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.SessionPool$PooledSession.writeAtLeastOnce(SessionPool.java:329)
  at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseClientImpl.writeAtLeastOnce(DatabaseClientImpl.java:59)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$WriteToSpannerFn.processElement(SpannerIO.java:1243)
  at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.spanner.SpannerIO$WriteToSpannerFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting and of course it should do a better job in dealing with the error message. I will follow up with an internal ticket. In the meantime, are you unblocked? If so, is it perhaps due to too high values in the withBatchSizeBytes() and/or withMaxNumMutations()?

Comment: My thruput I want is 15000/sec. But it is only writing 4000/sec. It should be due to 1MB and 5000 Mutations limit I set by default. Even with 1MB and 5000Mutations, I get this error. Wondering if it runs or not with 15000 mutations and 50MB setting. That's the goal. Each MB has 150Messages. So I would need 100MB for 15000 messages/sec process

Comment: I am still BLOCKED with the issue

Comment: Is it a new application or something starts to failing recently? I'm also wondering why you are seeing that error because the code shows that if the error happens, it should fall back to insert individual mutation group  (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/spanner/SpannerIO.java#L123). To troubleshoot deeper why it takes long time to insert, we need more information about the workload. Please create a support ticket if possible.

Comment: One possible scenario (without knowing the schema) is that the insert happens across many nodes (i.e., data is not ingested in order of and group of primary key of target table). The best practices for dataflow (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/dataflow-connector#writing-transforming) and bulk loading in general (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/bulk-loading) would apply here.

Comment: Workers: 40. I have a composite primary key (5 columns). Why Long time? I am not sure. I launched this dataflow from cloud-shell. We have about 50Million records in spanner as of now. No that much to say. Data Load: We must go thru Dataflow streaming job. this is the only source to put data in to it

Comment: I am not sure either without knowing the detail of your setup and schema. The best practices are there for a reason. Are you exploiting all of those? Please create a support ticket so that we can engage deeper to help you (https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/getting-support).

Comment: How many spanner nodes do you have? A general rule of thumb for a simple Dataflow load is vCPU/node otherwise Spanner gets overloaded and blocks on commit for a very long time.

Comment: Clarify previous comment 1vCPU of Dataflow worker per spanner node.... If you look at spanner API commit latency in stackdriver you may see commit latencies increasing until it blocks...

Comment: Spanner: 35 Nodes. Dataflow: 90 Workers (max). 
Still this error happens everyday and huge slowdown and afraid of data loss